# How to the add the img class to the surrounding div

Tags: jquery, html, image, addclass

I've got an img, which is wrapped into a div container. Now I want to add the img class to the surrounding div. How can I accomplish this with jQuery?

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <div class="imagebackgroud"></div>
  <div class="imageicon"></div>
  <img class="aligncenter">
</div>
```

The .imagebackground and .imageicon divs can be ignored, I want to add the img class ".aligncenter" to the .imagecontainer div.

Comment: `<img class="aligncenter">` ~!== `<img class="aligncenter" src="" alt="" />`

Comment: as roxon said, your img tag will probably not resolve if there is no src attribute

Comment: ah sorry, of course the img has a src attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".imagecontainer").addClass($('.imagecontainer img').attr("class"));
```

This assumes there is an image in the container.

```
$(".aligncenter").parent().addClass("aligncenter");
```

This assumes the image has a class of aligncenter and just puts that same known class on the parent.

Or you can use find:

```
$(".imagecontainer").addClass($(".imagecontainer").find('img').attr("class"));
```

EDIT
Ok so according to your comment...

```
$("img.aligncenter").parent().addClass("aligncenter")
```

should work. It's targeting all images with class "aligncenter" and then adding the class to the parent. While this looks very close to example 2, it is targeting specifically images with class aligncenter this way.

Here is a fiddle working:
http://jsfiddle.net/U5vRe/

Comment: Thanks Kai, code 1 & 3 are working, but one thing I forgot to mention: The img has several classes, how can i only add the class "aligncenter" to the div? At the moment its adding all classes.

Comment: it also applies the .aligncenter class to all .imagecontainer divs. it should only add .aligncenter to divs that have an img with class .aligncenter. because now all divs, even the ones without an .aligncenter img get the .aligncenter class and therefor being floatet, which the shouldnt. I hope thats not too confusing :s

Comment: I added an update, though it is very similar to #2, which should work. There's a fiddle attached to me that worked according to my limited data set.

Comment: cant get parent() to work at all. it just doesnt grab the div. any chance to only copy the .aligncenter with the third snippet your provided -> $(".imagecontainer").addClass($(".imagecontainer").find('img').attr("class"));

Comment: what version of jquery are you using? There should be no reason why .parent() won't work.

Comment: ah stupid me. parent() and closest() is working. the problem was that the image was also surrounded by an anchor, which i havent seen. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('img.aligncenter').parent().addClass('aligncenter');
```

Using parent() http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Otherwise:

```
$('.imagecontainer').addClass('aligncenter');
```

Comment: i also tried to target the div with `parent()`, but it doesnt work. The second code I cant use, because not all `img` have the aligncenter class. I only want to add the class .aligncenter to the divs whose images have this class.

Answer (score 1):

try it :)
http://jsfiddle.net/nlphuong/xm38X/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").parent("div").addClass($("img").attr("class"));
});
```

ps: first try with jsFiddle :))

Comment: I have updated my jsFiddle. with closest, it still work :-? is there any javascript error on your (firebug) console ?

Comment: i can see that its working in your jsfiddle, but not on my site. why is that? i also use jquery 1.8.3

Comment: using firefox then press Ctrl+Shift+J to see if is there any script error in your site, then try with simple script : alert(typeof jQuery); to check whether your jquery have loaded or not.

Comment: i check with firefox and chrome console, no error. i also use fancybox on the same page and its working fine with jquery.

Comment: ya closest() is working. thanks so much, was just a typo of mine, haha.

Comment: ^^ I see, no error in firefox console, but on firebug console i got TypeError: $(...).closet is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

$("img").closet("div").addClass($("img").attr("class"));

Comment: ya like i said in my previous comment this was a typo of mine. thanks for introducing me to clostest(). i was only checking the console with parent(), which was fine.